# React Native: navigation

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react native, this is an application that scans Qr codes I want to have two buttons one that scans again and one that redirects to a new screen called 'List' with the QR code data. However after scanning the QR code and every time i press the scan again or result button the expo application crashes this is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { decode } from 'base-64';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default function Scan({ navigation }) {
  
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Not yet scanned')
  


  const askForCameraPermission = () => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })()
  }

  // Request Camera Permission
  useEffect(() => {
    askForCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  // What happens when we scan the bar code
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    var master_key = '5486231058798416'
    // Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
    var rawData = decode(data);
    // Split by 16 because my IV size
    var iv = rawData.substring(0, 16);
    var crypttext = rawData.substring(16);

    //Parsers"
    crypttext = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext);
    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv); 
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(master_key);

    // Decrypt
    var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      { ciphertext:  crypttext},
      key,
      {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7}
    );

    // Can be Utf8 too
    var output_plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray).json();
    console.log("plain text : " + output_plaintext);
    setText(output_plaintext.json())
    console.log('Type: ' + type + '\nData: ' + data)
  };

  // Check permissions and return the screens
  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
      </View>)
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>No access to camera</Text>
        <Button title={'Allow Camera'} onPress={() => askForCameraPermission()} />
      </View>)
  }

  // Navigation
  function MyBackButton() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
  
    return (
      <Button
        title="Result"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('List');
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  // Return the View
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.barcodebox}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }} />
      </View>

      {scanned && <Button title={'Result'} onPress={() => MyBackButton()} color='black' />}
      {scanned && <Button title={'Scan again?'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} color='black' />}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  maintext: {
    fontSize: 16,
    margin: 20,
  },
  barcodebox: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code MyBackButton not just a function, it return a view -> crash.

Fix your func MyBackButton =>

```
// Navigation
  function MyBackButton() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
  
    navigation.navigate('List');
  }
```

Rename your MyBackButton -> myBackAction